# Socket.IO connection in React causes continuous reloads

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I've never had this problem before and can't seem to figure out what is causing it. I'm working on a project with an Express & Socket.io back end and a React front end (using create-react-app).

*server/index.js...*

Pretty standard and to my knowledge should work...

```js
const app = express();
const server = app.listen(config.port);
io.attach(server);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'build')));
  app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'index.html')));
}

io.on('connection', socket => {
  *blah blah blah*
});
```

*src/index.js...*

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.socket = io.connect(window.location);
  }

  render = () => {
    if (view === 'start') {
      return <StartContainer socket={this.socket} />;
    } else if (view === 'game') {
      return <Game socket={this.socket} />;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm actually in the process of testing deployment so I've been running `set NODE_ENV=production&& node server/index.js` to test the file serving in the Express app.

In development, I run two servers: one with create-react-app and another for the Express & Socket.io server. This issue doesn't occur in development.

So, I start up the server, go to localhost and the page keeps refreshing. If I remove the socket connection from `App` the issue goes away. Hopefully I'm not overlooking something super simple here. Any help is appreciated.

I left out some of the App component for the sake of brevity but if you suspect the issue may be elsewhere please let me know and I'll add more of it.

**EDIT** The issue is definitely on the client. I [served](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) the built React project and have same issue.

Comment: Did you check if both servers aren't pointing to the same localhost:port ?

Comment: @ManuelBlanco there are only 2 servers running in development and they are on different ports. This issue is only present when serving the files from the Express server (production).

Comment: Is the create-react-app in production too? Did you try running the create-react-app as development while the express/socket.io is production? Are there any components that check for the production flag in your express/socket.io server?

Comment: @SILENT The only change in the front end between development and production is the socket.io connection url. In dev it's `http://localhost:3001`(the port the Express server is on) and in prod it's `window.location`. Running the Express server in production and the React server independently results in the React server working and the Express one not. This is bc the front end served from Express still doesn't work and the React server is connecting to the Express server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

Before, this is what the connection was like:

```
this.setState({ socket: io.connect(config.socketIO) });
```

where `config.socketIO` was `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? window.location : 'http://localhost:3001'`

I assumed this would work because in the documentation it says `io()` defaults to `window.location`. Apparently passing `window.location` is not the same. The working solution so far is...

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  this.setState({ socket: io.connect() });
} else {
  this.setState({ socket: io.connect('http://localhost:3001') });
}
```

I should also note that I moved the connection into `componentDidMount`, hence the `setState`.